# What is $\mathbb{E}(X|Z)$ where $Z = X^2 + Y^2$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Pick a point $(X,Y)$ inside the unit square $[0,1]^2$ uniformly at random. Let $Z = X^2 + Y^2$. What is $\mathbb{E}(X|Z)$?

I have got $\mathbb{E}(X^2|Z) = Z/2$ but not sure where to go after that.

Comment: How about using $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X^2 + Y^2 = \rho^2]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X = \sqrt{\rho^2 - Y^2}]=\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{\rho^2 - Y^2}\mid X]$

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis Which leads to what?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter that's strange - I don't think that posters can delete answers. Can you please post the answer again? I'm interested in it. I also posted an answer yesterday, but I deleted it because my reasoning was wrong as Did pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is for the benefit of @PantelisSopasakis)

If $Z\leq1$ is given we may assume that $(X,Y)$ is lying on the quarter circle with radius $\sqrt{Z}$ in the first quadrant, uniformly distributed with respect to arc length, resp.,  to the polar angle $\phi={\rm Arg}(x,y)$.

(Think of $(X,Y)$ lying in a sector of the annulus $Z\leq X^2+Y^2\leq Z+dZ$. "In the limit" area measure on this annulus becomes arc length.)

It follows that in this case
$$E(X\>|\>Z)={2\over\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{Z}\cos\phi\>d\phi={2\over\pi}\sqrt{Z}\qquad(Z\leq 1)\ .\tag{1}$$
If $Z\geq1$ then the quarter circle becomes a circular arc of radius $\sqrt{Z}$ with polar angle $\phi$ bounded by  $$\alpha\leq\phi\leq{\pi\over2}-\alpha\ ,$$
whereby $$\cos\alpha={1\over\sqrt{Z}}\ .$$ Instead of $(1)$ we now have
$$E(X\>|\>Z)={1\over{\pi\over2}-2\alpha}\int_\alpha^{\pi/2-\alpha}\sqrt{Z}\>\cos\phi\>d\phi\qquad(1\leq Z\leq 2)\ .$$
I may leave it to you to simplify the result.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$I derived the same result and got `-2` for some reason... I had written: We need to find $\E[X {}\mid{} Z=\rho^2 ]$. Given that $Z=X^2 + Y^2 = \rho^2$, we may parametrize $X$ as $X=\rho \sin \theta$ with $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and for $\rho \in [0,1]$. Then $\E[\rho \sin \theta]=\rho \E[\sin \theta] = \rho \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\theta\in[0, \frac{\pi}{2})}\sin \theta\, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{2\rho}{\pi}=\frac{2\sqrt{Z}}{\pi}.$ (This holds for $\rho \leq 1$).  The question is whether $\phi$ is indep. of $Z$.